# Including Local Variables in Django Error Emails

Tags: python, django, error-handling, stack-trace

I have a site built in Django.

When an error occurs on the production site, Django automatically sends a stack trace to the email addresses listed in the ADMINS list in settings.py.

I would like this stack trace to include local variables for each stack frame (like the standard stack trace does when the site is in debug mode).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's really simple to set this up. Just put `'include_html': True` in the logging config of whichever handler is sending error emails for you.

For example (this is the default logging handler aside from the "include_html" line):

```
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false',],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
        'include_html': True
    }
}
```

This includes an html attachment in the error email with the contents of the error page you get when DEBUG=True. The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler) have a few more details and a note about security.

You could also look at setting up a logging handler which uses subclasses of `django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler` and `django.views.debug.ExceptionReporter` if you need  to customize things a lot more.

Comment: Is there a way to get Django's default logging config and override just the bits I need in my settings.py? This doesn't work, but shows what I mean: `from django.conf.settings import LOGGING
LOGGING['handlers']['mail_admins']['include_html'] = True`

Comment: Got it. It's: `from django.utils.log import DEFAULT_LOGGING as LOGGING
    LOGGING['handlers']['mail_admins']['include_html'] = True`